# Need to choose a Presentation Layer Pattern - MVP or MVVM for ASP.NET Web Forms and WPF Implementation

Tags: asp.net, wpf, mvvm, mvp

For my application, I have the requirement to develop the same functionality in a ASP.NET Web Forms application and a WPF disconnected application. I need to choose a presentation pattern that will accommodate both technologies smoothly. I was leaning toward MVP, using the MVC# framework; but it seems that all of the MVP frameworks are not really supported any more or need to be extended to support WPF. On the other side of the coin, MVVM seems to be the hot presentation pattern at the moment; but wikipedia mentions that there are drawbacks to MVVM when it comes to larger applications.

I need some guidance on choosing a pattern and an implementation framework that will not be deprecated in just a few short years. Is MVP dead for the .NET stack? Is MVVM the better choice? Is there an MVVM framework for ASP.NET Web Forms?

Any suggestions would be greately appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well to be frank, I dont know a thing about MVP. So all I can do is for MVVM. And the conception of MVVM is not scalable for larger projects is myth. Infact currently we have around 40+ projects in our solution and most of them, except few model assemblies are following MVVM. And its wonderful.

Heads up for you! MVVM is daunting at first hand, but once you have basic framework ready, it is the most test friendly pattern out there. One additional and rather significant advantage is, to proceed with work of designers and develpers seperately. Its a bliss when you integrate them. Purely all logic recides in VM and UI in View. so no chance of missing any feature to be unit tested.

My two cent. Hope it helps!

Comment: My main question still remains... Is there an MVVM framework that will work for ASP.NET Web Forms and WPF.